# Improve performance by increasing APP server memory for EhCache

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache

I am using Hibernate's second level caching with EhCache. Almost 90% of my calls are read only.
So to improve performance, planning to increase APP server memory(around 16GB) and expecting that EhCache will load maximum data and reduce my DB calls.

For this I have made following configurations

```
<defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="10000000"
    eternal="true"
    timeToIdleSeconds="1200"
    timeToLiveSeconds="1200"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">

</defaultCache>

<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
        maxElementsInMemory="500"
        eternal="true"
        overflowToDisk="false">
</cache>

<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
        maxElementsInMemory="500"
        eternal="true"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy = "LFU">
</cache>
```

Using this, I am trying to expect two things

1. If there is any update in DB, same object should get refresh in EhCache in 15 to 20 minutes. I know if I use `eternal="true"` which will ignore `timeToLiveSeconds="1200"`. How I can reload updated object in EhCache?
2. EhCache should use maximum memory provided to App server. Is there any way to allocate memory to EhCache?

Suggest if you have any other options with EhCache to improve performance and reduce DB calls.

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding expiry, I would recommend setting only `timeToLiveSeconds` to the value that works for you. If you can serve stale data for 15 to 20 minutes, that's the most efficient way of working. Do not set `eternal` which indicates no expiry should occur - ever. Also do not use `timeToIdleSeconds` which provides a weird contract: value is considered fresh if accessed. If you cannot server stale data, you will need a direct invalidation call, like `Ehcache.remove(key)` whenever your business logic updates the database entry.
2. Ehcache allows you to size the heap tier in bytes, however this incurs a runtime cost. One way of using the feature is to do tests, determine the consumed memory / entry count ratio and then use entry count in production.

Note that for point 2 you could look into [Ehcache 3.x](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/tiering.html) which offers an offheap tier allowing not only to use a lot of memory but also not have that memory impact garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks. I used `maxBytesLocalHeap` to set memory for ehCache. But I think it's not working as expected. I expect that eCahe must use entire memory, load all data in memory which reduce calls on DB. Secondly, with above parameter, is ehCache use memory from server itself or get it from machine. Like, server memory is 4GB and I assigned 2GB for ehCache which used from server itself.

Comment: the local heap bytes are taken from the Java heap, so if you have a VM with max 4GB and you give 2GB to ehache, only 2GB are available for the rest of Java objects.

Comment: Same thing I assumed. For testing, I just give 2GB to java server and 4GB to ehCache and still there is no any error or exception and application running well. So is this correct assumption what we are talking about.

Comment: How do you give 2GB to the JVM? Once you have told Ehcache to use 4GB, how do you load it up? These settings, if used and configured properly, will indeed make your application go out of memory.

Comment: That's what my point is. I have assigned 2GB memory to Tomcat where my application is running, and in same application, I have configure ehCache with 4GB. Ideally it should give me some error or exception but everything is fine.

Comment: Unless you start putting data into the cache, it will not fail as Ehcache cannot pre-allocate these 4GB. It will just never evict until the content of the cache grows beyond 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is fine.

1. If your database update is done using hibernate as well, Hibernate should evict the stale entries from the cache. They will be re-cached on the next attempt to
2. Do as @louis-jacomet said